# PHP converting ISO-8859-3 characters to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck in how to convert ISO-8859-3 to UTF-8 characters through PHP. The data is being retrieved from a MySQL database (set as utf8_unicode_ci). The characters which I am trying to convert are  ċ,ġ,ħ and ż.
I require that ċ is converted c
,ġ is converted g
,ħ is converted h
,ż is converted z

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: share your mysql table structure from where you are retrieving the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace, to replace multiple characters at once:

```
<?php
$str = "I require that ċ is converted c ,ġ is converted g ,ħ is converted h ,ż is converted z";

function _search_replace ($s) {
    $search_for = array('/ċ/', '/ġ/', '/ħ/', '/ż/');
    $replace_with = array('c', 'g', 'h', 'z');
    return preg_replace($search_for, $replace_with, $s);
}

print _search_replace($str);
```

Will output:

```
I require that c is converted c ,g is converted g ,h is converted h ,z is converted z
```

Comment: The problem seems to come from the data that I importing from the database. Your solution woks fine for any string declared in my php files, but not for anything imported from the database.